# How does the same React.createContext work in functional components and React.Components

Tags: react-context, react-functional-component

I learn React and now I do some React.createContext and have a question. I'm a beginner so have some learning curve please advice!

I understand that if I do like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
    <FirebaseContext.Consumer>{firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}</FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
export default FirebaseContext;
```

I later can do like this to define what the Context should Provider:
(in this case it's class handling Firebase functionality)

```
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './firebase';

ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>,

    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Now I can consume the Contect like this because it's been provided above:

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { firebase } = this.props;
        firebase
            .doSignInAnonymously()
            ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ....
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

My question here is what if I have in the above `App` a `render` that does not return `React.Components` but return like you see below a `function` `component` :

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Header:

```
function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <Hero />
        </header>
    );
}
```

How do I consume the Context created above now?

I have tried to use the `withFirebase` that I showed first above and here is it again:

```
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
    <FirebaseContext.Consumer>{firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}</FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
```

But if I wrap the `functional` `Component` `Header` in the `withFirebase` then I still cant use the `this.props` because they have no `this`.

I thought I could wrap the top class `App` with the `provider`
then children get access trough props but not for functional components or how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

`Header` in your case is a functional component, so you can access context via hooks:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import FirebaseContext from '..'

function Header() {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext)
    return (
        <header>
            <Hero />
        </header>
    );
}
```

I hope your React version supports hooks (v. 16.8)

Comment: Thanks that was good to know. I'm thinking what's the point then because I might as well do normal `import firebase from  ...` and then I get the same aggregation type of association  `firebase` right??

Comment: Correct - you can import firebase ref in the component as well.

Passing `firebase` ref via `props`/`context` let's you easier unit test your component (if it's a case for you), as you can replace real implementation of the service with the mock.

Comment: Thanks good info. React is a bit ambivalent sometimes creating a totally Rect.Component app or functional. Also Eslint is strange pushing suggestions about not using e.g. `..props` spreading or even if React.Component dont have `constructor` then it should be converted to a functional Component. Put then stuff don't work on the higher level. Feels like React ecosystem is a mashup, me coming from Android Java c++ .Net

Comment: What I recommend, is to drop class-based React approach, and move to functional API. 
If you have java / c++ background you are probably more comfortable with object-oriented concepts, like `class`, `constructor` etc, but the class-based React approach will probably disappear someaday (some of  the concepts, like `componentWillMount` are deprecated already)